# How can i get the ceil of a long Double?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, math

I have an array with photos and I want to display them on `UITableView`, the cell of the `UITableView` contain 4 `UIImageView`, so i want calculate the number of rows that will be contain the `UITableView`. lets say if have 5 photos I must divide 4 and gives 2 but the problem is when i divide this number it gives a long Double so I can't get the ceil of this number. this my code:

```
NSLog(@"%Lf", ceill([imageArray count] / 4));
```

In the console it gives that:

```
==> nan
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
NSLog(@"%Lf",cei, ceill([imageArray count] / 4));
```

simply prints whatever the value of `cei` is (assuming `cei` is a long double; otherwise the result is undefined).  You want:

```
NSLog(@"%Lf", ceill([imageArray count] / 4));
```

That said, is `[imageArray count]` really a `long double`, or is it `long` (an integer type)?  If the latter, don't use `ceill`; instead use:

```
NSLog(@"%ld", ([imageArray count] + 3)/4);
```